# Comparing two tables for different columns PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper, alter-table

I very new to PL SQL and I have encountered a problem. Hopefully its not too hard to solve and I'm just going about it all wrong. 
My problem is this: I have two tables with a different amount of columns. I need to run a check to see what the different columns are and then add them to one of the tables. 
For example:

Table 1 has 1 column called name.

Table 2 has 2 columns called name and id.

(name has the same data type in both tables)

In this case,  I would need to run a script that will check table 1 and 2, see that table 1 is missing the 'id' column and then add it to table 1.

Is this possible?

so far I have this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name  = 'TEST_TBL' OR TABLE_NAME  ='TEST_TBL1'
```

which returns the columns for both tables. I have looked everywhere on the internet with no luck at all. I have tried to do **intersect** and **join** but with no luck.

If anyone has any help or could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it so much!

Answer (score 0):

To get the different columns

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM user_tab_columns 
where table_name  = 'Table1' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ( SELECT COLUMN_NAME  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='table2') 
UNION
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM user_tab_columns 
where table_name  = 'table2' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ( SELECT COLUMN_NAME  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='table1');
```